# NSMutablearray to file with only Name + Score

Tags: xcode

I want to write an array to a file, but then I got this: (the file is an .txt file

```
<plist>
<array>
<string>Jeroen</string>
<real>9.5</real>
</array>
</plist>
```

In my code I have:

```
[Leerling writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];
```

But I want in the .txt file: NAME + , + SCORE  only, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can't use the built in function, you have to make your own.

Possible pseudocode solution:

> Make a NSMutableString. This will be the string that is written to
>   file.
>   Append the format you want to the string using the data from the
>   array.
>   Add a newline.
>   Write this string to file.

**Requested in comment**

```
NSMutableString *yourString = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];

for (int i = 0; i < [yourArray count]; i++) {
    YourObject *yourObject = [yourArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [yourString appendFormat:@"%s + %s\n", yourObject.name, yourObject.score];
}

[yourString writeToURL:yourURL atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Comment: Updated. Not tested though, sitting on Windows At the momemt.

Comment: Thx, but how can you get the name and score only from an array? object.name doesn't work

Comment: the object.name was just a made up object. I have no idea what you have in the array. I thought you had some object, but if you have a string already on this format then drop that part.